# Why $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ has no subfield index of $3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Show $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ has no subfield index of $3$, where $\mathbb Q$ is the rational number field.

In fact, I'm wonder about that statement is true.

May I ask you any idea?

Comment: It is known that an algebraic closure is an extension of degree 1, 2 or infinite. I don't remember how difficult it is to prove, though. Also, maybe ruling out 3 on its own is easier than the full result.

Comment: [Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) is a walkthrough for the Artin-Schreirer Theorem due to Keith Conrad.

Comment: @ Fimpellizieri: good find, but a bit overkill, isn’t it? Only the end of page 3 and the beginning of page 4 are useful here...

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, it answers more than the question asks for. This may or may not be good, depending on the asker's interest.

Comment: index or degree?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the infinite Galois extension $\overline{\Bbb Q}\mid \Bbb Q$ the [Artin-Schreier Theorem](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) is the natural result to use. Since the title suggests this context, it seems to be appropriate. We obtain that there is no finite index subfield of index $n>2$ - the only finite groups arising as absolute Galois groups are $1$ and $C_2$. On the other hand, every profinite group arises as a Galois group.